# Javascript call has old values on textbox change

Tags: javascript, c#, events, server

I have a situation where I have two textboxes side by side, and on the first one I (in server side code) add handlers as follows (note, I have to do this server side as the text boxes are created dynamically):

```
tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextBox_Changed);

// Thickness checker
if (ThicknessCheckColumn != "")
{
     tb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "CheckThickness(this,\'" + ThicknessCheckColumn.Replace(" ", "").Replace("_", "").Replace("-", "").ToUpper() + "\')");
}
```

Now the TextBox_Changed event writes to a database, and sets the value of Textbox2 based on the entry in Textbox1 and some database settings...

```
private void TextBox_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {lots of check and database access code here}
TextBox2.Text = Result
}
```

The javascript checks the value of checkbox 1, and produces warnings, errors etc.

Its all working, EXCEPT the warnings are for the previous value of Textbox2.

Its as if the code in the server side event is running AFTER the validation, or the actual textbox values are not changing until all functions have been resolved.

Is there a reason for this?  Is there a better way of calling the javascript validation after the server side event has finished EVERYTHING?

Javascript function is as follows:

```
function CheckThickness(textControl,checkcolumn) {
    var id = textControl.id;
    // Go get the check value
    var checknumber = ""
    $('form input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        id.toString()
        if (id == checkcolumn) {
                checknumber = this.value;
        }
    })
    // Do the compare
    if (checknumber > 12)
    {
        alert("Proceed with caution!");
    }
    if (checknumber < lowerlimit) {
        alert("LThis blade has not been coated with the recommended thickness,\nbut can still end up within the finished size tolerance.\n\nProceed with caution!");
    }
}
```

UPDATED = 7th August....

So following on from this, is it possible for me to place on the textbox "textbox_changed" event to call a server side event, and to get a status back from this, to call the javascript conditionally?   So that I can do the checks on the actually real data at server side?

Something like (pseudo code here)...

tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler('set retstatus = call TextBox_Changed;  if retstatus = "Y" then call javascript_for_alert');

public sub string TextBox_Changed(....)
{
    ... blah blah...
    if (mycondition == true)
    {return "Y"} else {return "N"}
}

Otherwise, how do I get the javascript to run on the current value, and not the old value???

Comment: Can you show us the javascript function CheckThickness please?

Comment: function CheckThickness(textControl,checkcolumn) {
        var id = textControl.id;
        // Go get the check value
        var checknumber = ""
        $('form input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            id.toString()
            if (id == checkcolumn) {
                    checknumber = this.value;
            }
        })
        // Do the compare
        if (checknumber > 12)
        {
            alert("Proceed with caution!");
        }
        if (checknumber < lowerlimit) {
            alert("Too low");
        }
    }

Comment: Note - original question amended with additional follow on question - see above

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: the server side method TextBox_Changed is called after the JavaScript validation.

Client side click handlers are fired before the click submits the form to the server. The client side validation can only use the value of Textbox2 that appears on the page, before your server side handler has changed it.

Comment: So following on from this, is it possible for me to place on the textbox "textbox_changed" event to call a server side event, and to get a status back from this, to call the javascript conditionally?

Something like pseudo code here)...

tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler('set retstatus TextBox_Changed;  if retstatus = "Y" then call javascript');

public sub string TextBox_Changed(....)
{
    ... blah blah...
    if (mycondition == true)
    {return "Y"} else {return "N"}
}

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can use AJAX to send the input value to the server after the text has changed and then depending upon the result you can update the other textbox. Question: why do you think you need to add the click handlers on the server?